# py2neo error in rest.py :: httplib.HTTPException as err:

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I have been using py2neo on my local machine and it's been working great.  However, when I installed it out on my server I received an error before it said Successfully Installed.

This was the error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/py2neo/cypher.py", line 112
    except rest.BadRequest as err:
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/py2neo/rest.py", line 345
    except httplib.HTTPException as err:
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Sure enough when I try and use py2neo out on my server I get an error:
     invalid syntax (rest.py, line 345)

Locally I'm running python 2.7.2 where as on the server I'm running 2.5.2  Is this a known issue with the python versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on the website, py2neo is only compatible with Python 2.6 and upwards. Sorry!